# Convert all br tags into one universal <br />

Tags: php, preg-replace

need a simple preg_replace to convert all `<br>` `<br/>` and all possible br combinations to `<br />`.

This needs to work in order so i can process a string ie: 
`$output = preg_replace('', '<br />', $input)`

Thanks everyone!

Comment: BTW you know that <br/> isn't legal HTML right? Legal HTML is <br>. <br/> is XHTML.

Comment: cletus, `<br />` is fine in HTML 4, it will pass validation and won't cause any problems in browsers either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One RegEx to rule them all:

```
$output = preg_replace('/<\s*br[^>]*>/i', '<br />', $input);
```

Answer (score 6):

[Obligatory HTML parser comment]

If you're working with unknown and non-consistent HTML (as it sounds like you are), then put down the regex, you might hurt yourself. Finding a list of tags and altering a document is what HTML parsers were built for.

Learn the [PHP DOM Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and save yourself a lot of heartache.

Comment: Obligatory +1 following obligatory HTML parser recommendation

Answer (score 0):

/< ?[bB][rR] ?/? ?>/

Comment: This covers at least 95% of all combinations, so I do not unterstand the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

Try this pattern

```
<\s*[bB][rR]\s*\/?\s*>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$output = preg_replace('/< ?[bB][rR] ?\/? ?>/', '<br />', $input);
```

Comment: *sigh*... the commenting thing stripped out the extra space that was supposed to be in there. here's another one which it wouldn't work for: `<br clear="all" />`